# Grunt + Yeoman - How to stop rewrite linked JS files in index.html?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have a Angular project which is build with Yeoman and Grunt. Everytime if I run command:

```
sudo grunt serve
```

Is app normally launched but in index.html are deleted some linked libraries from bower_components directory.

**FXP:**

```
<script src="bower_components/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
```

So I must everytime revert changes in index.html file in git before I can continue in testing.

Is any possibility how can i solve this annoying problem?

Thanks for any help.

### **EDIT:**

I tried following:

Installed:

```
npm install grunt-script-inject
```

**GrunFile.js**

```
 // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: new RegExp('^<%= yeoman.app %>/|../')
      },
    scriptinject: {
      dev: {
         srcs: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components/path/to/src/plugin.js',
                '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components/path/to/src/plugin2.js'] ,//order is important if this sciprt will be concated and minified
         html: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html', //file that as the block comment to look for a place to insert the script tags
         without: '<%= yeoman.client %>/' //this script will be used to remove this block of string of script tag file location
        }
      }
    },
```

**And**

```
 grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'scripinject',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });
```

But now, after the grunt serve i see following error:

```
Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "scripinject" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just because it has not been mentioned 'scripinject' should be 'scriptinject' in grunt.task.run. Hence the 'Task "scripinject" not found'.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved using the **--s** in bower install command

So:

```
bower install --save  angular-translate
```

Works fine.

Here is documentation:

http://bower.io/docs/api/#install

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
In index.html I added the following code:

```
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
```

and every time I ran `grunt serve` or `grunt build` commands, grunt rewrote it to:

```
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

So I looked into `bower_components/highcharts-release/bower.json` file and saw:

```
{
  "name": "highcharts",
  "version": "v4.1.4",
  "main": [
    "highcharts.js",
    "highcharts-more.js",
    "modules/exporting.js"
  ]
}
```

I changed it to:

```
{
  "name": "highcharts",
  "version": "v4.1.4",
  "main": [
    "highcharts.js",
      "modules/heatmap.js"
  ]
}
```

and everything is fine now. Hope it will help someone, even this is a quite late answer.